# phpDesigner 8 - Git integration

Tags: git, github, phpdesigner

I'm supposed to be figuring out how to get phpDesigner 8 working with Git, and by extension, GitHub.  I've set up my GitHub account and have both the shell and desktop client installed on my computer, and I followed some vague instructions on how to make phpDesigner recognize Git (it involved directing it to a path containing the git.exe file).  I also attempted to integrate Git with GitHub so that I'd be able to access files without having to constantly log in and out of the GH website, but every time I try committing a file through phpDesigner, none of the changes I've made are reflected in the site's copy of the file.  There are no notifications about merge or commit requests either, so from the way I see it, Git is committing files to my hard drive for no real effect.

I feel like I didn't set something up properly, or I'm not selecting the right command.  I select the "commit" option, rather than "commit file" when attempting to test anything, but nothing seems to work.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> the way I see it, Git is committing files to my hard drive for no real effect

That's the way Git works. Committing is an entirely local operation.

To send your commits to GitHub you need to do a [`push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push). I have no idea how to do that from phpDesigner, but look for something in the Git menu that says push.

Based on their website it looks like there is the ability to run a "custom Git command". You might want to try using this to run `git push` if there isn't a dedicated menu operation for pushing.

Comment: I entered "push" into the custom command option and all that happened was that phpDesigner froze.  Just to be sure that nothing happened, I checked my GitHub repository to see if the file changed.  It's just the same as before.  You wouldn't happen to know if there's anything easier to work with, would you?  I know almost nothing about Git or GitHub and I'm not sure if the frustration is worth it.

Comment: @user3521737, "easier" is subjective. Git is thoroughly documented, and where its documentation may be hard to read there are countless third-party resources where you can get help. I'm not sure what you're looking for, but Stack Overflow isn't for software recommendations.

Comment: I've tried the push command and attempted to commit my changes to the remote GitHub repository.  Again, it just froze phpDesigner and I'm at a complete loss as to what I should do.  The command I'm using is as follows.

    push [repository URL] master

I've ommitted "git" because phpDesigner apparently takes care of that part already.  I've checked the remote repository as well just to see if anything had changed, and nothing did.

Comment: Never mind, I think it's working now.  It's stupid because you can't directly commit to GitHub through phpDesigner, at least from what I've seen.  If you have the desktop client on your computer, you have to first save changes through phpDesigner, then add/commit (depending on whether or not the file's been added yet), at which point the commit will be noted in the desktop client.  THEN you have to sync/publish (one of those options will be available) to the remote host, and it's not until you've danced this stupid dance that your files will FINALLY be updated on the site.

Comment: "It's stupid because you can't directly commit to GitHub through phpDesigner…" I'm not aware of _any_ tool that lets you "commit directly to GitHub" aside from the limited editing you can do through the GitHub web UI. As I suggested in my answer, Git commits _are always local, by design_. This is a deliberate part of the way Git works. Commits are local, then you can _optionally_ push them to one or more remotes. Switching gears a bit, in general the push syntax is `git push <remote-name> <branch>` (note that you would use a remote _name_—`origin` would be a common one—not a remote URL).